# Convert internal enum 'TileLayoutIndex' to int

Tags: c#, microsoft-band

I'm getting an error message about converting to an int.

Here's the code:

```
// create the object containing the page content to be set
PageData pageContent = new PageData(
    messagesPageGuid,        
    TileLayoutIndex.MessagesLayout, // Specify which layout to use for this page
    new WrappedTextBlockData(
        (Int16)TileMessagesLayoutElementId.Message1,
        "This is the text of the first message"),
    new WrappedTextBlockData(
        (Int16)TileMessagesLayoutElementId.Message2,
        "This is the text of the second message"));
```

And here's the internal enum code:

```
internal enum TileLayoutIndex
{
    MessagesLayout = 0,
};
```

Why am I getting an error?

Update:

```
Guid messagesPageGuid = Guid.NewGuid();

// create the object containing the page content to be set
PageData pageContent = new PageData(
    messagesPageGuid,
```

This Guid thing might be the problem

Comment: I'm debugging this while waiting for an answer and I saw that it's working in other places in the method. Why isn't it working in this place?

Comment: It looks like I can't convert the enum to an int inside the PageData(. Any workarounds?

Comment: Please indent your code correctly before you post.

Comment: We can't fix an error unless you tell us what the error is

Answer (score 1):

You are not using an integer, so you need to cast it:

```
// create the object containing the page content to be set
PageData pageContent = new PageData(
    messagesPageGuid,        
    (int)TileLayoutIndex.MessagesLayout, // Specify which layout to use for this page
```